# How to match the last where clause by using regular expression?

Tags: regex

If I have a query like the following:

```
select ... from table_1 inner join (
  select ... from table_2 inner join table_3 where ...) where (...)
```

How do I match the last where clause, I tried `where.+?$`, however, it will match the second last where instead of the very last one.

The `?` should make this math non-greedy, which means it should only match the last `where`.

Any ideas?

Comment: The "?" should make this math non-greedy, which means it should only match the **very first** "where".

Comment: What language are you using ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
.*(where.+)$
```

The `.*` will be greedy, so it will match up to the last `where`. Then `where.+` will match the `where` clause and put it in capture group 1.